# Optimizing Python function with Parakeet

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, simulation, parakeet

I need this function to be optimized as I am trying to make my OpenGL simulation run faster. I want to use [Parakeet](http://www.parakeetpython.com/), but I can't quite understand in what way I would need to modify the code below in order to do so. Can you see what I should do?

```
def distanceMatrix(self,x,y,z):
    " ""Computes distances between all particles and places the result in a matrix such that the ij th matrix entry corresponds to the distance between particle i and j"" "
    xtemp = tile(x,(self.N,1))
    dx = xtemp - xtemp.T
    ytemp = tile(y,(self.N,1))
    dy = ytemp - ytemp.T
    ztemp = tile(z,(self.N,1))
    dz = ztemp - ztemp.T

    # Particles 'feel' each other across the periodic boundaries
    if self.periodicX:
        dx[dx>self.L/2]=dx[dx > self.L/2]-self.L
        dx[dx<-self.L/2]=dx[dx < -self.L/2]+self.L
    if self.periodicY:
        dy[dy>self.L/2]=dy[dy>self.L/2]-self.L
        dy[dy<-self.L/2]=dy[dy<-self.L/2]+self.L
    if self.periodicZ:
        dz[dz>self.L/2]=dz[dz>self.L/2]-self.L
        dz[dz<-self.L/2]=dz[dz<-self.L/2]+self.L

    # Total Distances
    d = sqrt(dx**2+dy**2+dz**2)

    # Mark zero entries with negative 1 to avoid divergences
    d[d==0] = -1

    return d, dx, dy, dz
```

From what I can tell, Parakeet should be able to use the above function without modifications - it only uses Numpy and math. But, I always get the following error when calling the function from the Parakeet jit wrapper:

```
AssertionError: Unsupported function: <bound method Particles.distanceMatrix of <particles.Particles instance at 0x04CD8E90>>
```

Comment: One possible optimisation you could also make would be replacing the 12 uses of `self.L/2` with a single local variable.  That may do something. :-) (although this doesn't help with the Parakeet issue... sorry)

Comment: I would guess the boolean indexing isn't supported but I'm not sure. I do know that allocating intermediary arrays like `xtemp` and `dx > L/2` is wasteful. Although your vectorized code might be the fast in regular numpy, with a JIT compiler you're better off using blunt for-loops!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parakeet is still young, its NumPy support is incomplete, and your code touches on several features that don't yet work.

1) You're wrapping a method, while Parakeet so far only knows how to deal with functions. The common workaround is to make a @jit wrapped helper function and have your method call into that with all of the required member data. The reason that methods don't work is that it's non-trivial to assign a meaningful type to 'self'. It's not impossible, but tricky enough that methods won't make their way into Parakeet until lower hanging fruit are plucked. Speaking of low-hanging fruit...

2) Boolean indexing. Not yet implemented but will be in the next release.

3) *np.tile*: Also doesn't work, will also probably be in the next release. If you want to see which builtins and NumPy library functions will work, take a look at Parakeet's [mappings](https://github.com/iskandr/parakeet/blob/master/parakeet/mappings.py) module.

I rewrote your code to be a little friendlier to Parakeet:

```
@jit 
def parakeet_dist(x, y, z, L, periodicX, periodicY, periodicZ):
  # perform all-pairs computations more explicitly 
  # instead of tile + broadcasting
  def periodic_diff(x1, x2, periodic):
    diff = x1 - x2 
    if periodic:
      if diff > (L / 2): diff -= L
      if diff < (-L/2): diff += L
    return diff
  dx = np.array([[periodic_diff(x1, x2, periodicX) for x1 in x] for x2 in x])
  dy = np.array([[periodic_diff(y1, y2, periodicY) for y1 in y] for y2 in y])
  dz = np.array([[periodic_diff(z1, z2, periodicZ) for z1 in z] for z2 in z])
  d= np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

  # since we can't yet use boolean indexing for masking out zero distances
  # have to fall back on explicit loops instead 
  for i in xrange(len(x)):
    for j in xrange(len(x)):
      if d[i,j] == 0: d[i,j] = -1 
  return d, dx, dy, dz
```

On my machine this runs only ~3x faster than NumPy for N = 2000 (0.39s for NumPy vs. 0.14s for Parakeet). If I rewrite the array traversals to use loops more explicitly then the performance goes up to ~6x faster than NumPy (Parakeet runs in ~0.06s):

```
@jit 
def loopy_dist(x, y, z, L, periodicX, periodicY, periodicZ):
  N = len(x)
  dx = np.zeros((N,N))
  dy = np.zeros( (N,N) )
  dz = np.zeros( (N,N) )
  d = np.zeros( (N,N) )

  def periodic_diff(x1, x2, periodic):
    diff = x1 - x2 
    if periodic:
      if diff > (L / 2): diff -= L
      if diff < (-L/2): diff += L
    return diff

  for i in xrange(N):
    for j in xrange(N):
      dx[i,j] = periodic_diff(x[j], x[i], periodicX)
      dy[i,j] = periodic_diff(y[j], y[i], periodicY)
      dz[i,j] = periodic_diff(z[j], z[i], periodicZ)
      d[i,j] = dx[i,j] ** 2 + dy[i,j] ** 2 + dz[i,j] ** 2 
      if d[i,j] == 0: d[i,j] = -1
      else: d[i,j] = np.sqrt(d[i,j])
  return d, dx, dy, dz
```

With a little creative rewriting you can also get the above code running in Numba, but it only goes ~1.5x faster than NumPy (0.25 seconds). The compile times were Parakeet w/ comprehensions: 1 second, Parakeet w/ loops: .5 seconds, Numba w/ loops: 0.9 seconds.

Hopefully the next few releases will enable more idiomatic use of NumPy library functions, but for now comprehensions or loops are often the way to go.

Comment: Thank you! I resurrected this account to upvote your answer, even though you responded to it on reddit as well. Better late than never.